# Delete data from JPA without using SQL

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

im familiar with this following way to delete the data (just the data ,not the entity itself)
from the entity

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + className)
                    .executeUpdate();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

there is another way to do that like to provide the entityname and then reomve all the data .

Comment: What is `not the entity itself`? Do you want set `null` to all fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using SQL in your code but JPQL, JPA Query Language.

There is no other way to delete all data at once, except by loading all of them and deleting them one by one. It's not even possible with criteria queries since they don't support delete operation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. in this case both NativeSQLQuery and JPQL resolve to the same thing. What you did is JPQL way. The following you could write a nativeSQLQuery

```
EntityManager em = ...;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery ("SELECT * FROM EMP", Employee.class);
```